# Does ShowWindow() sends a WM_SIZE message?

Tags: c, winapi

My testings shows that when I call `ShowWindow()`, a `WM_SIZE` message is sent.

Can I rely on this behavior (because I can't find a documentation for it)?

Comment: Use [`WM_SHOWWINDOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632645(v=vs.85).aspx) to know when the window is shown or hidden.

Comment: In theory it would only do it if the size was changed, e.g. with `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`.

Comment: I second Jonathan Potters theory and suggest that if you cannot find a documentation stating this behavior I wouldn't rely on it...

Comment: Given that *Raymond Chen* did not confirm that `WM_SIZE` is guaranteed, I think it's safe to say that you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN, calling the [`ShowWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) function with one of

- `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE`
- `SW_MAXIMIZE`
- `SW_MINIMIZE`
- `SW_RESTORE`,
- `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`
- `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED`
- `SW_SHOWNORMAL`

will cause the window to either minimize, maximize, or get restored.

And still according to the MSDN, the [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) message has `wParam` values for these cases (minimizing, maximizing, and restoration) which indicates that a `WM_SIZE` message is sent in these cases.

I'm not sure about the behaviour of other flags in the `ShowWindow()` function such as: (`SW_HIDE`, `SW_SHOW`, `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`, `SW_SHOWNA`, `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`).